# WPF Binding to objects

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I'm trying to reset data in my object bound to a simple form (some textboxes and a couple of buttons).

I have 2 objects that were created separately, but have the same information. Object 1 is bound to a form using DataBinding. Object 2 is there to be able to reset Object 1 to original values.
Whenever user edits data everything is fine, and Object 1 is updated with new values, while Object 2 stays the same. I'm having a problem with a scenario when user edits some data, and then clicks Reset Button which calls code that looks like this:

```
Object1 = Object2
```

Values get reset, but now when user edits data again, both Object1 and Object2 values are updated. And I can't reset anymore.

How can I reset Object1 values without making Object2 update-able at the same time?
And can someone explain why Object2 becomes update-able after resetting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say Object1=Object2, you are simply making Object1 point to wherever object 2 is pointing. They are sharing the same reference and hence both are getting updated at the sametime.

My suggestion would be to deep clone.  I don't know the complexity of your classes. This code was very handy for me.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx

So whenever you reset Object1, create a deep cloned object passing in Object2 and assign that to Object1.

Comment: That's what I thought, just needed to confirm. And DeepClone does work perfectly. Are there any performance concerns when using DeepClone that you are aware of? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well you are basically serializing the source and deserializing, so theoretically the heavier the object this operation will take more time. I have played around with it using TypedDataSet Structures with multiple tables and associated data without any noticeable performance loss.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll play around with it. I don't have crazy large objects, so it shouldn't affect the performance much.

Answer (score 1):

Object2 becomes bound as Object1 is now just a reference to Object2. to avoid this try copying just the properties of Object2 into Object1, or figure out some way to clone Object2 and then assign the clone to Object1.